# Linear transformation of orthonormal vectors and orthogonality of transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question:**

Let $v_1, v_2,\cdots, v_n$ be orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Show that $Av_1.Av_2,\cdots,Av_n$ are also orthonormal if and only if $A\in \mathbb{R^n}$ is orthogonal.

**What I have Done:**

$P: Av_1.Av_2,\cdots,Av_n$ are orthonormal

$Q: A \in \mathbb{R^n}$ is orthogonal

$Q \Rightarrow P$ is quite straightforward. But what confuses me is the proof of $P \Rightarrow Q$.

If $P$, then we could write
$$
(Av_i)^T(Av_j)=v_i^TA^TAv_j=
\begin{cases}
1,i=j\\
0,i\neq j
\end{cases}
$$
But what is next. Even though we could say $A^TA = I$, which I do not think I could conclude directly from the formulas we have, how should I prove $AA^T = I$, which is the *premise* to define a orthogonal matrix.

Thank you in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are almost there. Just write the matrix $A^{T}A$ in the basis $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ (you have done it already, in fact, just haven't realised it).

Comment: Since you know that $A$ is full rank, its left inverse is equal to its right inverse, so if $A^TA=I$, $AA^T=I$.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин Thank you. But I do not really understand what you say. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Paul I just realize $A$ is full rank. But could I directly conclude $A^TA =I$ without necessary reasoning?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, yes, you can conclude it directly. Notice that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is an orthonormal basis so every vector can be written as $\sum c_iv_i$. The formulas for $v_iA^{T}Av_j$ (you made a mistake, by the way, they are actually formulas for $v_i^{T}A^{T}Av_j$, which is just an inner product of $v_i$ and $A^{T}Av_j$) allow you to compute $A^{T}A(\sum c_iv_i)$. Turns out it is equal to $\sum c_iv_i$ which means $A^{T}A=I$ by definition of the identity matrix.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин Sorry, it was a typo. And I still do not really understand. Do you mean $v_{j}$ could be written as linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$? What if they are linearly independent?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, I made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, since $\{v_i\}$ is an orthonormal system of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they form an orthonormal basis. Therefore, each vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as the sum
$$v = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)v_i,$$
where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This gives us
\begin{multline*}
A^{T}A(v) = A^{T}A(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)v_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)A^{T}A(v_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(A^{T}A(v_i), v_j)v_j \\= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)\sum\limits_{j=1}^nv_j^{T}A^{T}A(v_i)v_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n (v, v_i)\delta_{ij}v_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (v, v_i)v_i = v
\end{multline*}
where
$$\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases}1 & i=j \\ 0 & i \ne j\end{cases}.$$
Therefore for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$A^{T}Av = v$$
which means
$$A^{T}A = I.$$

Like @Paul mentioned in the comments, $A^{T}A = I$ means $A^{T} = A^{-1}$ and thus 
$$AA^{T} = AA^{-1} = I.$$

Comment: Now I finally understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mr.Robot, No problem

Comment: I am wondering how you could see it through without any difficulty and so fast. Is there a theorem or something related to this topic?

Comment: @Mr.Robot Well, not really, just quite a good understanding of these concepts. The orthogonal matrices are actually pretty simple. Once you understand how they work everything becomes easy. I can't really explain it here (there are a lot of aspects involved) but I'm sure you will learn all of it soon. Just keep doing those excercises=) Also, uh, do you mind marking my answer as corrext and/or upvoting it?

Comment: I have already done it. Thank you again for your advice and solutions.